# BaseHelper not found Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, user-management

Since a couple of weeks, I have to work on a Laravel project (which I never did before).

When I try to enter `/user/create` I get the error:

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError
Class 'BaseHelper' not found
```

with a link to a UserController file that tries to call this function:

```
\BaseHelper::checkLimit('user'))
```

So I tried to include the `BaseHelper` with an `use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper` in the `UserController.php` right after `use App\Base\Base` and a `use BaseHelper` right after `use Base` at the beginning of the `UserController` class.

So my code looks like this:

```
use App\Base\Base;
use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper;

...

class UserController extends Controller
{
    use Base;
    use BaseHelper;

    ...

    public function create()
    {

    ...

    if (User::count() >= \BaseHelper::checkLimit('user')) return redirect(url('user'))->with('danger', 'License limit reached (' . User::count() . '/' . \BaseHelper::checkLimit('user') . ')');

    return view('base::user.create');
    }

...

}
```

But now this error show's up: `app\Base\Controllers\UserController cannot use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper - it is not a trait`

As I mentioned earlier, I have hardly any knowledge on Laravel and still learning much stuff, so I do not know whether I did the right thing in the first place and how to fix this new error afterwards.

Comment: This is less of Laravel issue and more of a PHP issue. If you're using `use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper;`, then you shouldn't do `\BaseHerlper`, just `BaseHelper` without the `/`. Secondly, is this actually a trait? I.e. `trait BaseHelper { ... }`. If so, then you can include it via `use BaseHelper`, then call the function like `checkLimit('user')`. If it's simply a class, with a `static` function `checkLimit()`, then you remove the `use BaseHelper;` and just do `BaseHelper::checkLimit()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing imports and traits.

Imports are usually done around the beginning of the file, which you seem to have done correctly:

```
use App\Base\Base;
use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper;
```

Traits are within classes, and is a completely different concept altogether. e.g.

```
class User extends Model
{
    use Authenticatable;
}
```

See:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php
to understand what traits are.

I assume `BaseHelper` is a class, and not a trait.

So don't include the following in the controller:

```
use BaseHelper;
```

also

`\BaseHelper` should be `BaseHelper`.

The correct code should be:

```
use App\Base\Base;
use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper;

...

class UserController extends Controller
{
    use Base; // I don't know if this is a trait
    // use BaseHelper; // REMOVE

    public function create()
    {

    ...

    if (User::count() >= BaseHelper::checkLimit('user'))
        return redirect(url('user'))->with('danger', 'License limit reached (' . User::count() . '/' . BaseHelper::checkLimit('user') . ')');

    return view('base::user.create');
    }

...

}
```

Comment: `\BaseHelper::checkLimit` should also be `BaseHelper::checkLimit` as it's imported at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Do you mean at the beginning of the file? When I change `use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper;` to `use BaseHelper;` the error changes from `app\Base\Controllers\UserController cannot use App\Base\Helpers\BaseHelper - it is not a trait` to `Trait 'BaseHelper' not found` the same applies to deleting `use BaseHelper;` from the beginning of the class

Comment: @user14692598 No, I mean after the `UserController` part

Comment: changing both did it for me, thanks guys, now the checkLimit function is not defined, but I guess programming this is my part now